# Zend Framework + Doctrine - Duplicated insertions

Tags: database, zend-framework, doctrine

I've integrated Zend Framework 1.11.9 with Doctrine 2.1 following this tutorial : http://www.michaelgallego.fr/blog/?p=45 (it's in french btw)

It's working well except that when I persist an object, it's inserting the same object twice.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using in your `Action`?

Comment: Here is the code I'm using in my action
\n
`$user = new Application_Model_Users();
$user->setFirstname('Clément');
$user->setLastname('Blanco');
$user->setEmail('toto@titi.com');
$user->setPassword('password');
$this->em->persist($user);
$this->em->flush();`

Comment: And I've got this line in my init of this controller.

$this->em = Zend_Registry::get('entityManager');

Comment: So after the `->flush()`, there are two rows in your database?  Is there any way to check how many changes are in the queue before the `flush` call?  Perhaps its worth doing a call to `clear()` before you call `persist()`?  I would also try checking if there are any entries straight after you call persist - just to double check.

Comment: I tried to clear() before persist but still get the same record inserted twice.
I also tried to exit() before the flush() and I don't get any record inserted.
I tried to clear() before the flush() and after the persist() but I also don't get anything inserted.

Any other suggestion ?

Comment: Could you post all the code in `Application_Model_Users`?  I guess this extends `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract`?  Have you overridden any methods?

Comment: Here it is : http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/G8maKhK3i
It does not extend this class and I didn't override anything ...

Comment: Ah yes, Ok.  If it was me then, I would try running the code with a debugger.  Do you have [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/) setup?   This will allow you to step through the code line by line, so you can see where the two are coming from.

Comment: That's what I wanna do but I've some problems running an XDebug session. I built a virtualBox Debian server to host my web server for dev purposes but I can't get XDebug working with NetBeans 7.0.

Comment: I use it in Eclipse, and its was fairly easy to setup - I don't use NetBeans though...  So are you running Netbeans on your VM or your host OS?

Comment: Ah, as far as I know you'll need to have Netbeans and your webserver on the same machine.  Its generally easier to develop when you have a webserver running on the machine you're working on - so its probably worth setting this up.  What is your host OS, and is there any particular reason you needed to have a virtual Linux server to host your site?

Comment: I've moved to install everything on my Windows XP with a WAMP server now. Still the same problem of double assertions ...

Comment: Ok, a recent version of wampserver should have Xdebug packaged with it. See if you can get it working with Netbeans.

Comment: Ye it's alright. I've just used this version https://github.com/ralphschindler/NOLASnowball/tree/doctrine2-managed of an implementation of Doctrine 2.1 with the latest ZF Version. Everything's allright. Anyway, thanks for your support.